# Laravel 5.4 - Saving Excel data into dynamically created columns in MySQL

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I have a internal webpage that makes data from excel searchable and readable from a 3rd party excel export file. The webpage allows for the uploading of multiple excel files in which the data gets read and stored in a MySQL database.

We want to update the application to keep a history of the uploaded data (it's data that has monthly values) so we can easily search, filter and generate graphs from the uploaded data.

So I am using Laravel 5.4 and have `maatwebsite\excel` to import and parse the excel file.
The Excel file always consists of the following columns ([Dummy File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SPATxNM40nc5qG_xYhwbuLgFoTW3gveeKbL-Gs9dp78/edit?usp=sharing))

`| Item group | item # | item name | Item Currency | <month> <year> |`

After `Item Currency` there is always 36 columns for the past 3 years of data from the current month so a column would be named like `dec 2017`

Now in Laravel I have created a Model for the item named `Item` and a model for the monthly values named `ItemMonthly`

Now I am able to read the file and create columns dynamically in the database but I feel like this is very ugly and not efficient at all:

[(Gist) Code for Models and Excel Function](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7c039ec24bd5eafd6b5adc936f0f18bb)

### Biggest problem

Because I need to read all the monthly data and since I need them in order of month I can't really rename all the columns as far as I know. I need to be able to get all the columns to render in a Highchart graph and in a Datatable. and some items don't have the same monthly data (some only go till 2015 for example.

### Needed advice

I've read a couple of solutions here some of them saying instead of creating columns in MySQL just store the monthly data as a json object in a single column.

Some answers just completely advice on changing from MySQL to MongoDB

I am kind of at a loss to find the best approach for this, and am sincerely wondering if MySQL is the right way to go. The solutions I have been trying so far all seem to involve really hacky ways of doing this.

If there is more info needed please let me know. I don't want to write an immense wall of text but I also want to provide the correct amount of information.

Many thanks!

Comment: If the dynamic columns in the excel sheet are months and years, it seems like `Month` and `Year` should be columns in your table and something like `dec 2017` should be translated to a row with `12` for month and `2017` for year.   Is there a reason this approach doesn't work for you?  You shouldn't have dynamic columns in MySQL.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. I have added a link to a dummy spreadsheet to see how it looks. All the monthly values are from the previous 36 months (excluding the current month) but tomorrow this would already change because it would be february so if I were to get an export now it would still be jan 2015 till dec 2017. But tomorrow a export would have feb 2015 till jan 2018.